# Controller function not found on the server in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache2, codeigniter-3

So I got exactly this 404 error :

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /adminigniter1/Usercontroller/insert was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

When I wanted to call a function from the controller, from what I read about it has to do with the .htaccess file(and I placed that in my source folder adminigniter1), but mine seems to look ok:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /adminigniter1/index.php
</IfModule>
```

From my index.php I send to that controller function like this:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo base_url('Usercontroller/insert') ?>">
```

And this is my controller :

```
<?php

class Usercontroller extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Usermodel');

}
public function index() {
    $data["content"]= "user/index";
    $data["getStatus"] = $this->Usermodel->getStatus();
    $this->load->view("main",$data);
}
public function insert() {
    $datai= $this->input->post();
    
    if(isset($datai)){
        echo $datai['txtApartament'];
        exit;
    }
}
```

}

What can be wrong ?

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file in the _adminigniter1_ directory, or at the same level as it?

Comment: Is in the adminigniter1 folder.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the reason for that, I will post it here since some one can have this problem. All the issues were on apache2 side:

If you use ubuntu go :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

There you will have to edit field like this :

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

In my case AllowOverride was set to None, so you will have to set it to All, another thing, check the root for your localhost /var/www/html/ in my case, to be ok!